# Iframe is not scrolling on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, css, iphone, iframe, mobile-safari

I have an embed on a page. But when I open it on iPhone 7(Safari), it doesn't scroll. If I change the screen orientation from portrait to landscape, the scrolling works. After that if I change the screen orientation to portrait, the scrolling will work.

I also tested on iPhone 6s(Safari), it works without any issues.

Any suggestions?

Comment: iframe support is generally not very good on mobile platforms. I suggest you use jQuery and [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) it into your page dynamically if that's what you want to do with your iframe.